Issue in Spring Authorization Server and Spring Cloud Gateway refresh_token flow
I have created Spring Authorization Server and Spring Cloud Gateway and everything looks perfect, but I found a problem in the gateway  and specifically in the flow based on the refresh token. When the user logs in, SAS returns an access token, an oidc token, and a refresh token, which are stored in the SCG memory. The SAS session cookie has a duration of 30 minutes and it is used by SCG to prolong the time of access token. After the cookie expires, SCG starts using the refresh token. Each exchange request also replaces the oidc token in SAS, but SCG does not replace it in its memory. When the user decides to log out (RP-Initiated Logout), SCG sends the first id_token returned by SAS. For SAS, this token is invalid and throws an exception.
Is there a way to configure the SAS not to refresh the id_token, or to configure the SCG to replace it in memory on a refresh request?
Here is my SAS configuration:
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http
                .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).getEndpointsMatcher();
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("HDonev")
                .password("123456")
                .roles("DNSPR", "SIGSPR")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        List<String> aud = List.of("http://localhost:8080");
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("aca392b5-e4a7-43fa-aa94-3c6f5b5211f1")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"))
                .clientName("some client name")
                .clientAuthenticationMethods(c -> c.addAll(List.of(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST, ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUris(strings -> strings.addAll(Set.of("http://localhost:9090/home.html", "http://localhost:9090/login/oauth2/code/oauth")))
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED)
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(43200))
                        .idTokenSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                        .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                        .build())
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .setting("subsystem", "13900")
                        .setting("client.allowed.resources", aud)
                        .build())
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:9090")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> oAuth2TokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            if (context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN && context.getPrincipal() instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
                RegisteredClient registeredClient = context.getRegisteredClient();

                Set<String> authorities = authenticationToken.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                context.getClaims().claims(claims -> {
                    List<String> updateAUD = new ArrayList<>();
                    updateAUD.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) claims.get(JwtClaimNames.AUD));
                    updateAUD.addAll(registeredClient.getClientSettings().getSetting("client.allowed.resources"));
                    claims.put(JwtClaimNames.AUD, updateAUD);
                    if (!authorities.isEmpty()) {
                        claims.put("roles", authorities);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = context.getPrincipal();
                User user = (User) authenticationToken.getPrincipal();
                JwtClaimsSet.Builder claims = context.getClaims();
                claims.claim("user", user);
                claims.expiresAt(Instant.now().plusSeconds(3600));
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }


    public RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = this.generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        // @formatter:off
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings providerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .authorizationEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/authorize")
                .tokenEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/token")
                .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/introspect")
                .deviceAuthorizationEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/device_authorization")
                .tokenRevocationEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/revoke")
                .jwkSetEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/jwks")
                .oidcUserInfoEndpoint("/connect/v1/userinfo")
                .oidcLogoutEndpoint("/connect/v1/logout")
                .setting("settings.authorization-server.change-password-endpoint", "/oauth2/v1/change")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofMinutes(60));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:9000"));
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }
}

Аnd here ere is my SCG application.yml:
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: backend
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/book/**
          uri: http://localhost:8080/api/book
          filters:
            - TokenRelay
            - SaveSession
        - id: change-password
          uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/v1/change-password
          predicates:
            - Path=/oauth2/v1/change-password
          filters:
            - AddRequestParameter=client_id, ${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauth.client-id}
            - AddRequestParameter=redirect_uri, http://localhost:9090/home.html
            - TokenRelay
        - id: static
          uri: http://localhost:5500
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oauth:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/v1/authorize
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/v1/jwks
            token-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:9000/connect/v1/userinfo
        registration:
          oauth:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            client-id: aca392b5-e4a7-43fa-aa94-3c6f5b5211f1
            client-secret: 123456
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: openid
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: true


a server sets cookies with a Set-Cookie header. This header instructs the browser (NOT the gateway) to set the cookie. So it would be the browser that fails to replace the cookie, if that is indeed the case. It could also be that you are not providing the correct domain for the refresh token cookies which is why these don't get correctly set / sent by the browser. Since you have not provided any code (and also request / response for the refresh request) can't help you any further.

As I said, as long as the SAS cookie is active, there is no problem, but when it expires, the CCG starts exchanging the refresh token for an access token, and then the id_token is also refreshed. SCG does not save the new id_token. When the user logs out, SCG sends the old id_token and an exception is through in SAS.

you just ignored my comment and repeated what you said before. Do your requests NOT come from a browser? show me the code where you think SCG saves/doesn't save stuff

SCG is used as middleware between browser and SAS and it keeps all tokens in its own repository and does not provide them to the browser. It only sends its own cookie and the SAS cookie. This is the reason to prefer SCG in the BFF pattern when we use Spring Framework.

If a SCG session expires, shouldn't it be invalidated and the tokens it contains, including the refresh token, be deleted? To me, SCG should not be able to refresh tokens of an expired session. The real problem stands probably there.

You are absolutely right, maybe I didn't ask the question clearly. It's about the SAS session, not the SCG session. When the SAS session expires, and the SCG has a valid session, the SCG starts using the refresh token to exchange access token. I apologize if I have contributed to the confusion.

"SAS session cookie ... is used by SCG to prolong the time of access token". Nope: only the user agent has access to the SAS session cookie. This cookie is not seen by SCG, which can only use the refresh token to get new access tokens (unless SCG re-initiate an authorization code flow, in which case the user agent would present the session cookie to SAS and might get an authorization code without the user having to fill login form, but SCG should use refresh token if present).

Also, SCG should replace all tokens it keeps in session after a refresh. have you checked the token refresh answer on SCG? Does it contain an ID token? And by the way, have you double-checked that the first token response contains a refresh token?

Hello, after several hours of debugging I can say that:

On the authorization_code flow SAS returns all three tokens and SCG writes them. When initiating a logout a minute or two after logging in, SCG sends the oidc token and everything works perfectly.
On the refresh_token flow SAS exchange all tokens, SCG receives them in the response, but only records the access token and refresh token and ignores the oidc token.


Important: I found that when refreshing the access token, whether based on a valid cookie or via the refresh_token  flow , the oidc token is replaced by the SAS and ignored by the SGC, which in turn leads to the above issue.

This question is similar to: Spring OAuth2 client performs Back-Channel Logout with an expired ID token. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
